# How to define Sweave driver on RStudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, sweave

I'm using `sweave` package to make a report based on my R code. However, since some code chunks take too much time to process, I'm planning to use cacheSweave package to avoid this issue.

In [`cacheSweave`'s vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cacheSweave/vignettes/cacheSweave.pdf), it says I need to specify a driver

```
Sweave("foo.Rnw", driver = cacheSweaveDriver)
```

However, I would like to keep using the "*Compile PDF*" button inside RStudio, so that it automatically runs `Sweave` command and `pdflatex` as well.

**How do I tell RStudio to use that specific driver when calling `Sweave` function?**

The expected result is that when I process the following "*.Rnw*" code twice (example based on code taken from `cacheSweave`'s vignette), the second time will be much faster since data is cached.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<cache=TRUE>>=
set.seed(1)
x <- local({
  Sys.sleep(10)
  rnorm(100)
})
results <- mean(x)
@
\end{document}
```

`Sweave` function help says *Environment variable SWEAVE_OPTIONS can be used to override the initial options set by the driver*. So I tried the following command in RStudio console,

```
Sys.setenv(SWEAVE_OPTIONS="driver=cacheSweaveDriver")
```

then "Compile PDF" twice again, but no success.

Comment: It might be worth switching to **knitr**, which will natively let you cache particular chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

As posted in this ["ghost" blog](http://recalculatereality.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/using-cachesweave-or-pgfsweave-with-rstudio/), I created a file named *.Rprofile* in my working directory with the following content:

```
library(utils)
library(cacheSweave)
assignInNamespace("RweaveLatex", cacheSweave::cacheSweaveDriver, "utils")
```